# Angular 2 - Using chips instead of labels

Tags: html, angular, typescript, label

I am developing a website in angular 2, where it is possible to add skills to the website like "programming". Right now i am generating labels when adding new skills and I have a button to remove the skills. What i want is to use chips (see image)

What i have right now:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skillArray; let i = index">
  <label id = "skills"for="skill">{{skill}}</label>
  <button type="button" (click)="removeSkill(i)">X</button>
</div>

<div id="addSkill">
  <input #newSkill type="text" placeholder="Add your skills here">
  <button (click)="addToSkill(newSkill.value)" class="btn-addskill">Add Skill</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
export class ProfileComponent {
url: any = "";
editMode = false;
skillArray: string[] = [];

addToSkill(skillInput:string) {     
  if (!this.skillArray.find(x => x == skillInput)) {
    this.skillArray.push(skillInput);
  }
}

removeSkill(i: any) {
    this.skillArray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Chip:
[image]

I know how to make the chip by following https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_contact_chips_close , but i have difficulty generating a chip instead of a label

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I tried doing the following:    <div *ngFor="let skill of skillArray; let i = index">
      <label id ="skills" for="skill">{{skill}}</label>
      <span id="removeskill" type="button" (click)="removeSkill(i)">x</span>
    </div>

But it does not work

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: I fixed it :) It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple **[Chips Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EPo3ze3r2sOjuNJTilYz?p=preview)** that can help you to build form

**view**

```
<div class="control">
  <label class="control-label">Skills</label>
  <ul class="chips-list" (click)="token.focus()" [ngClass]="{ focus: focus }">
    <li *ngFor="let skill of skillArray; let i = index" class="chip">
      <i class="chip__icon"></i> 
      {{ skill }} 
      <span class="chip__close" (click)="removeSkill(i)">&times;</span>
    </li>
    <li class="chip--input">
      <input #token type="text" class="chip-input-control" placeholder="Add your skills here" 
        (keydown.enter)="!!onKeydown(token)" 
        (focus)="focus = true" 
        (blur)="focus = false">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**component**

```
skillArray: string[] = [];

focus: boolean = false;

onKeydown(tokenInput: HTMLInputElement): void {
  let value = tokenInput.value;
  if (value && value.trim().length && !this.skillArray.find(x => x == value)) {
    this.skillArray.push(value);
  }
  tokenInput.value = '';
}

removeSkill(i: any) {
  this.skillArray.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: `#token` is just template reference like `#newSkill` in your example

Comment: Oh okay, what about this part: (click)="token.focus()" [ngClass]="{ focus: focus }